# Do we need the [mysql-like] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I ran across the [mysql-like](/questions/tagged/mysql-like) and I am not sure if it is needed.  You would think these questions would be tagged with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [like](/questions/tagged/like) but the "LIKE" tag wiki states:

> This tag is not for the SQL reserved keyword LIKE.

I am guessing that since the [like](/questions/tagged/like) specifically states this is not for SQL that resulted in the fabulous [mysql-like](/questions/tagged/mysql-like) tag.

I have a few questions about this tag and what steps we should take with it:

- Do we burninate [mysql-like](/questions/tagged/mysql-like)?
- Should we have specific RDBMS "LIKE" tags?  This could lead to [sql-server-like](/questions/tagged/sql-server-like), etc.
- Can we just expand the tag wiki of [like](/questions/tagged/like) to include SQL?
- Or should a sql specific "LIKE" tag be created?  At this time, there are also other tags which are sql based for like including [like-operator](/questions/tagged/like-operator) and [like-keyword](/questions/tagged/like-keyword).

The [like-operator](/questions/tagged/like-operator) has 240 questions so possibly that should become the sql "like" tag and the others (except [like](/questions/tagged/like)) are burninated.

Thoughts?

Comment: Some of the other "SQL keywords that need to be disambiguated" follow the pattern of `sql-foo`, so `sql-like` might be better here than `like-keyword`/`like-operator`.  But yes, otherwise murder `mysql-like` with extreme prejudice.

Comment: The [tag:like] tag needs to be burninated as well, while we're here.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming the original `like` to `social-like`

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104023, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142241

Comment: @Destrictor the process for that has already been started, the relevant questions are being disambiguated by using `facebook-like`.

Comment: @slugster I get the idea that that will encourage people to use google+-like and other similar tags as well though =/.

Comment: @Destrictor Yeah, that's what I mentioned in the comments on my answer - if there is a vendor or technology specific `like` that works differently then it should have its specialised tag, so currently we would have `facebook-like`, `google-like`, `sql-like` (assuming that there are legit dev questions related to the google like).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burnination) defines *burniate* as:

> A complete meltdown.

I say we completely melt down this tag as it's simply ***not*** [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) specific. Otherwise, we may as well create a tag for each DBMS and it's respective operators. A [sql-like](/questions/tagged/sql-like) tag would definitely be more appropriate.

**Update**

I've retagged all [mysql-like](/questions/tagged/mysql-like) to [sql-like](/questions/tagged/sql-like) and have requested that the OP's of questions with [like-operator](/questions/tagged/like-operator) request a synonym added of [sql-like](/questions/tagged/sql-like). How do I get a mod to *burniate* this tag?

Comment: I do agree the tag should be renamed to sql-like instead of mysql-like

Comment: Once there are no questions tagged with `mysql-like` the tag will disappear on its own

Comment: **Please do not request an outright burnination** and then leave it at that - there is still a lot of `facebook-like` tags to do, and typically those users have no clue how to tag let alone retag. As mentioned by bluefeet the tag will disappear once it isn't used (i.e. when the work is done).

Comment: @slugster I believe he was referring to the `mysql-like` tag none of the others

Comment: @bluefeet If so then I think the correct approach is to request a synonym, so `mysql-like` gets automatically matched to `sql-like`?

Answer (score 3):

As one who has spent a good amount of time cleaning up a [particular `like` tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142241/i-would-like-to-clean-up-like), I think we should keep the specific variants and blacklist the generic term (as per [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174440/do-we-need-the-mysql-like-tag#comment521552_174440)).

Some form of the tag needs to remain because people want to talk about it, and it is a [reserved keyword in ANSI SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249891/online-reference-listing-all-standard-sql-keywords).

Outright burnination of [like](/questions/tagged/like) may be too extreme and dramatic - you will find in many of the instances there are precious few other tags.

So don't get rid of [mysql-like](/questions/tagged/mysql-like), set your sights on [like](/questions/tagged/like) instead. And be prepared - it's a long process to clean it up.

Comment: I understand getting rid of `like`, but should we have a database specific `mysql-like` tag or should there be a `sql-like` instead?  There would be no need to have `mysql-like`, `sql-server-like`, `oracle-like`, etc

Comment: @bluefeet Agreed - unless the product specific `like` works differently then we should be able to cover them all with just `sql-like`.

Comment: `sql-like` + RDBMS tag seems like a good way to do it to me